# RTL8821CE driver installed, but not active

Tags: networking, drivers

After reinstalling ubuntu-desktop via apt-get and a kernel update for AMDGPU 5000 series support, I found that I couldn’t find the WiFi option in the settings app. I chrooted into my machine via a live USB with the drivers working and tried reinstalling the drivers. The drivers were already installed on the latest version. Is my driver mall functioning or disabled?

I’m using Ubuntu 21.04 using the 5.11.0-16-generic kernel

Comment: secureboot is disabled ?

Comment: You've provided no release details; nor if using a LTS release which kernel stack you're using.  As *drivers* are actually kernel modules; the kernel details do matter, but you've provided none.

Comment: Why did you reinstall ubuntu-desktop, and what do you mean a kernel update for AMDGPU? Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.