# RTL8821CE driver stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: drivers, wireless, rtl8192ce

I've had to install the driver per https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce a couple times on an ASUS laptop and each time it works for a while before breadking.  I have looked at dozens of "solutions" although none have really resolved the problem permanently (ie, I have to uninstall/reinstall the driver after a while).  Now, however, I can not get my Wifi to run at all without a USB dongle.

Per [RTL8821CE driver installed, but not active](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356313/rtl8821ce-driver-installed-but-not-active), @heynnema, requested sharing the following to facilitate finding a resolution:

```
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 ~  sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for jg: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcf0ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: ipv6leakintrf0
       serial: 4a:c3:07:5b:2c:e5
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx984827c6b66c
       serial: 98:48:27:c6:b6:6c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic ip=192.168.1.129 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11g
~  cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
 ✘  ~  cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Any guidance/assisted would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED to add output per request for additional info in response by @Jeremy31:

```
~  modinfo 8821ce | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'; mokutil --sb-state
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/8821ce.ko
vermagic:       5.11.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_FileMaskEfuse:default drv Mask Efuse value:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
SecureBoot disabled
```

2nd edit per request for more info per @Jeremy31 below:

```
~  dmesg | grep 8821  
[    2.155492] 8821ce: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.191521] 8821ce: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.197826] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.219923] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0009 address=0xfede7000 flags=0x0000]
[   12.399578] proc_dir_entry 'net/rtl8821ce' already registered
[   12.399671] Modules linked in: rtl8821ce(OE+) rfcomm dummy cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btusb btrtl videobuf2_common btbcm btintel videodev bluetooth mc ecdh_generic ecc rtsx_usb_ms memstick rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress edac_mce_amd ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_amd snd_pcm kvm crct10dif_pclmul amdgpu snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi_event joydev snd_rawmidi iommu_v2 gpu_sched drm_ttm_helper ttm aesni_intel snd_seq crypto_simd drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer cryptd glue_helper rapl input_leds cec 8821ce(OE) wmi_bmof asus_nb_wmi serio_raw rc_core i2c_algo_bit k10temp snd fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch
[   12.400393]  rtw_drv_proc_init+0x3b/0xc8 [rtl8821ce]
[   12.400660]  rtw_drv_entry+0x28/0x1000 [rtl8821ce]
[   12.400930] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 323 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.c:296 rtw_drv_proc_init+0x54/0xc8 [rtl8821ce]
[   12.401134] Modules linked in: rtl8821ce(OE+) rfcomm dummy cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btusb btrtl videobuf2_common btbcm btintel videodev bluetooth mc ecdh_generic ecc rtsx_usb_ms memstick rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress edac_mce_amd ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_amd snd_pcm kvm crct10dif_pclmul amdgpu snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi_event joydev snd_rawmidi iommu_v2 gpu_sched drm_ttm_helper ttm aesni_intel snd_seq crypto_simd drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer cryptd glue_helper rapl input_leds cec 8821ce(OE) wmi_bmof asus_nb_wmi serio_raw rc_core i2c_algo_bit k10temp snd fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch
[   12.401402] RIP: 0010:rtw_drv_proc_init+0x54/0xc8 [rtl8821ce]
[   12.401687]  rtw_drv_entry+0x28/0x1000 [rtl8821ce]
[   12.402034] Error: Driver 'rtl8821ce' is already registered, aborting...
```

3rd edit per request for additional info from @Jermemy31:

```
✘  ~  dmesg | grep 8821
[    2.080005] 8821ce: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.080989] 8821ce: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.085513] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.114711] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0009 address=0xfed97000 flags=0x0000]
[    2.115070] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 308 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/hal/rtl8821c/rtl8821c_halinit.c:122 rtl8821c_power_off+0x62/0x8d [8821ce]
[    2.115163] Modules linked in: 8821ce(OE+) rapl cec input_leds(+) rc_core asus_nb_wmi(+) hid_multitouch(+) snd serio_raw wmi_bmof efi_pstore snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea ccp k10temp snd_pci_acp3x sysfillrect cfg80211 sysimgblt soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap nvme crc32_pclmul ahci libahci xhci_pci nvme_core xhci_pci_renesas i2c_piix4 wmi video i2c_hid hid
[    2.115211] RIP: 0010:rtl8821c_power_off+0x62/0x8d [8821ce]
[    2.115309]  rtw_hal_power_off+0x3e/0x41 [8821ce]
[    2.115397]  hal_read_mac_hidden_rpt+0x143/0x226 [8821ce]
[    2.115476]  rtl8821c_read_efuse+0x35f/0x599 [8821ce]
[    2.115549]  read_adapter_info+0xe/0x15 [8821ce]
[    2.115621]  rtw_hal_read_chip_info+0x76/0x81 [8821ce]
[    2.115698]  rtw_pci_primary_adapter_init+0x148/0x36b [8821ce]
[    2.115774]  rtw_drv_init+0x2cf/0x6a3 [8821ce]
[    2.115888]  rtw_drv_entry+0x4c/0x1000 [8821ce]
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `modinfo 8821ce | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'; mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -v 8821ce`

Comment: Thanks, @Jeremy31.  I tried that but nothing seemed to change after reboot.  My settings still indicate "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

Comment: any results from terminal for `dmesg | grep 8821`

Comment: @Jeremy31 output from `dmesg | grep 8821` added as 2nd edit to original post above

Comment: Results also for `dkms status`

Comment: @Jeremy31 ```~  dkms status      
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)```

Comment: try `sudo dkms install rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 -k $(uname -r)` and reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 diidn't change anything: 
```~  sudo dkms install rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 -k $(uname -r)
[sudo] password for jg: 
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already installed on kernel 5.11.0-37-generic/x86_64```  I rebooted anyway and, as expected, still not working.

Comment: Ok, lets uninstall for that kernel version first `sudo dkms uninstall rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 -k $(uname -r) && sudo dkms install rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 -k $(uname -r)` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 done.

Comment: I can see you have 2 different versions of the driver installed, try `echo "blacklist rtl8821ce" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ce.conf` and reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 done but no evident change in WiFi status

Comment: Please edit the question to add new results for `dmesg | grep 8821`

Comment: @Jeremy31 results of `dmesg | grep 8821` added as 3rd update to original.

Comment: Try `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and reboot as wifi power management could be causing an issue

Comment: @Jeremy31, I switched the wifi power option from 3 to 2 in default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and rebooted.  Still no wifi, though.

Comment: If it worked well in the past and suddenly quit after installing updates and rebooting you should probably file a bug report against the kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31, thanks for your dogged assistance in helping me try to figure it out.  It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall the driver using another wifi usb adaptor

Commands I'd used:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall rtl8821ce-dkms
sudo modprobe rtl8821ce
```

then I retired the usb adaptor and rtl worked again

PS: that's happening in Ubuntu 22.04LTS... again!